# How to merge data from two columns which is context dependent?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, if-statement, merge

In a file with following data structure:

**The input file is below data until the column (PB).**

```
contig  pos    GT    PGT       PID     PG      PB     updated_Block
2      5426    0/1   0|1       5398   1|0   1311       1311 
2      5427    0/1   0|1       5398   0/1   .          1311
2      5434    0/1   0|1       5398   1|0   1311       1311
2      5454    0/1   0|1       5398   0/1   .          1311
2      5457    0/0   .          .     0/0   .          .
2      5467    0/1   0|1       5467   0|1   1311       1311
2      5480    0/1   0|1       5467   0|1   1311       1311
2      5483    0/0   0|1       5482   0/0   1667       1667
2      5518    1/1   1|1       5467   1/1   .          1311
2      5519    0/0   .         .      0/0   .          .
2      5547    1/1   1|1       5467   1/1   .          1311
2      5550    ./.   .         .      ./.   .          .
2      5559    1/1   1|1       5467   1/1   .          1311
2      5561    0/0   .         .      0/0   .          .
2      5576    0/1   0|1       5576   1|0   1311       1311
2      5599    0/1   0|1       5576   1|0   1311       1311
2      5602    0/0   .         .      0/0   .          .
2      5657    0/1   .         .      1|0   1311       1311
2      5723    0/1   .         .      1|0   1311       1311
2      6414    0/1   .         .      0|1   1667       1667
2      6446    0/1  0|1      6446     0|1   1667       1667
2      6448    0/1  0|1      6446     0|1   1667       1667
2      6465    0/1  0|1      6446     0|1   1667       1667
2      6636    0/1  .          .      1|0   1667       1667
2      6740    0/1  .        6740     0|1   1667       1667
```

**The output file is input data plus the last column (which I need to calculate).**

PID represents the block and PGT represents one of the data in that block, generated by one particular program.
Another program generates the same type of information for the same data set - PB is the block and PG is one of the data in that block. **These two programs emit the values and block info based on different probability test.**

**So, from the above data output:** Data belonging to the block PB (1311) is from the same block as PID (5398, 5467 and 5576). I just need to merge as many blocks as possible to make largest possible block. So, I just need to find the overlapping blocks and merge them to create a larger block set. **The updated block should look like the last column (which I typed by hands).**

**Details:**
1311 from PB overlaps with 5398, 5467, 5576 from PID - so they make a large block. You can see that PID (5398) is associated with PB (1311) in some lines, that means any line that has PID (5398) but missing PB actually belongs to the PB (1311) because PID was previously associated with it. The updated block can have a unique values same as PB.

I am confused on how to approach this problem. I wanted to build a list of dictionary first, but I will still have some problem with reading each line until no large block can be made, after which we start reading the other block values to make another largest block.

Below is a partial solution:

I can create another file or data object like this:

`PB_PID_group = data_frame.groupby("PI")["PID"].unique()`

which gives me:

```
PI
.             [., 5398, 5482, 5467]
1311    [5185, ., 5398, 5467, 5576]
1667                      [., 6446]
3352                            [.]
935                             [.]
Name: PID, dtype: object
```

I have to drop the first line in the above output and `periods(.)` from the other lines. **But, this is still not a data in table format. I also need to fix this.**

So, now I load two files and read both files line by line:

```
file_1 = file_1.split('\n')
file_2 = file_2.split('\n')

for line in file_1 and file_2:

    again split lines by tabs and then

    PB_file1 = file_1[6]
    PID_file1 = file_1[4]

    PB_file2 = file_2[0]
    PID_file2 = file_2[1].split(', ')
```

Now, I search and update the values in update_PB

```
    if PB_file1 is an integer:
        update_PB = PB_file1
    elif:
        PB_file1 = '.'
        if PID_file1 in PID_file2:
            update_PB = PB_file2
    else:
        update_PB = '.'
```

So, this search and update loop continues by read 1st line in file_1 and all the lines in file_2; again 2nd line in file_1 and all the lines in file_2 and continues until all the lines in both files are complete.

Any suggestions. Any help?

Comment: Can you create an ouput dataframe that would show us exactly what you want as a final result.

Comment: The input file is the above data until the column (PB). The output file just adds the last column to the input file based on the info in PB and PID column.

Comment: Hi @TedPetrou: Do you understand the problem now? You can see that PID (5398) is associated with PB (1311) in some lines, that means any line that has PID (5398) but missing PB actually belongs to the PB (1311) because PID was previously associated with.

Comment: I just gave a simple answer below. This will attach all the PB that match up to each PID. It will duplicate rows where PID are mapped to multiple PB

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are just replacing the periods with a random PB on the same PID group.

```
df.groupby('PID')['PB'].transform(lambda x: x.replace('.', x.sort_values()[-1]))
```

From your last comment it seems you just want the max of each PID group.

```
df['updated_Block'] = df.groupby('PID')['PB'].transform('max')
```

And if you need to make the PID periods have a corresponding period entry then set them back to a period with the following.

```
df.loc[df['PID'] == '.', 'updated_Block'] = '.'
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I am really not sure how to work this out. Its such a complicated context.

Comment: I can probably merge it using unique values. `PB_PID_group = data_frame.groupby("PB")["PID"].unique()`. But, need to drop the `periods (.)`. After that create a table and read the two file together (line by line), and then update the value in the last block using if then. I am not able to drop the periods in pandas though.

Comment: The above code duplicated the lines with non-unique values. The line with pos value 422 (and similarly others) were duplicated 3 times with 3 different updated block values.

Comment: If there are non unique PB for each PID which PB do you want to map to each PID? The most frequently occurring?

Comment: Hi @Ted Petrou. Thanks for trying to help. I am not tyring to update based on frequency. Like I said, if a PID value is associated with PB in any line, that means any other lines with that PID will need be updated with that associated PB. Thats it !  Sorry this is so complicated.

Comment: So, what do you want to do with duplicates? When a single PID has multiple PB? Which PB do you choose? How do you avoid this duplication?

Comment: I think I have found a partial solution. Just wait. I am hoping you can help me with this nightmare. Look for the updates in my question in 5 mins. :)

Comment: I gave it another shot. Seems like you are just replacing the periods with another value.

Comment: Yes, but I am updating the period with PB value if that value is associated with PID else where (some other line) in the file. Can you please look into the loop I want to use? But, I am having trouble reading two files at once line by line. Also, these two files don't have equal number of lines.

Comment: What would happens if PID 5398 has PB 1311 and 1667? What do we fill the period with?

Comment: I was aware this was going to happen in some instances. That would mean two PB can now be merged into one PB. So, We update with large PB number.

Comment: What do you mean by 'large PB'? Most frequent, greatest number?

Comment: Did you look into my proposed if-else loop method? I am finding it hard to read two files at once. I will sleep over it tonite, hope to see some updates on my question tomorrow.

Comment: The large PB means greatest number. This problem is from genetic phasing. So, we are trying to grow the size of haplotype as much as possible. Is there is evidence that two blocks are bridged by some info/lines we update the block values. I am hoping it's not confusing you.

Comment: What's wrong with my current answer? It replaces the period with the largest PB for each PID.

Comment: The large PB means greatest number. So, when PID 5398 has PB 1311 and 1667 - the block with PB 1311 will be updated with 1667, block with PB 1667 will be updated with 1667, where PB is '.' but PID is 5398 block will be updated with 1667. This problem is from genetic phasing. So, we are trying to grow the size of haplotype as much as possible. If there is evidence that two blocks are bridged by some info/lines we update the block values. I am hoping it's not confusing you.

Comment: Hi @Ted: I just check and found you updated your answer. I will try the answer tomorrow. I  currently outside my office and checking answer over the phone. Thanks much to you !

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a dictionary for each PID. Is PB unique for each PID?

You could group by **PID** and **PB**, delete the duplicates and *nan* values if any. Then you would have a table **PID PB** to create the column you need.

Comment: PB is unique for each PID in most instances but not always. Thats the main problem with me. This is just a part of the big data.

Comment: Can you write me a code in pandas. I am trying my best nothing fruitful happening.

Comment: How do you want to deal with those cases? That is, what to do when a PID has more than one PB? You just want to go ahead and merge each PB to each PID (i.e many-to-many merge)?